# How to convert the velocity field to a pressure field to information relating to sound level?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, acoustics, computational-physics, phase-velocity

I am studying jet mixing noise and I am given a velocity field, with Vx, Vy, Vz in x and y coordinates. I wanted to know if there's a method in which I could find some information relating to the sound level produced from the pressure field.

Answer (score 0):

If your end goal is an estimation of the sound level then you don't need to calculate the pressure field first, you can estimate the sound level directly from the characteristic jet velocity using Lighthill's eighth power law, assuming your velocities are subsonic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighthill%27s_eighth_power_law

Comment: How exactly would you apply Lighthill's 8th power law to the velocity field?

Comment: You would need to calculate a representative velocity for the jet from the velocity field.